# c++ comma operator in between cout and return value

Tags: c++

```
return cout<<"NO"<<endl,0;
```

I have a few questions in this code. I've already tried searching for an explanation but none seems to explain it clearly. Does 'cout <<' return something? If so, does this code means that it could return either of the two values? If so, how does it know which value to return?

Comment: Please read up about the comma operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does `cout <<` return something?

It returns `std::ostream&` reference to `cout`, unless the user overloaded `operator<<(std::ostream&, T)` to return something else.

> If so, does this code means that it could return either of the two values?

No, the code always returns 0. Unless the user overloaded `operator,`.

> If so, how does it know which value to return?

[The built-in comma operator always returns the second value.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: thank you but i have another question if you call a function like this: somefunc(), x +=3; what actually happens in this code? which goes first?

Comment: @glennmark `somefunc()` is evaluated first, provided this is a built-in comma operator. For user-defined comma operator the order is indeterminate.